# Submit more than one value to database

Tags: php, forms

I have an add to cart button in the homepage. After collecting their product to their cart, the user will submit (process) the list of the product in the form. Since there would be more than one product that they will submit, the form is going to be added automatically (I do this with `foreach` function).

```
        foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm) {
                    echo '<input name="product_name">'.$cart_itm["product_name"].'/>';
                    echo '<input name="product_price">'.$cart_itm["prduct_price"].'/>';
    }
```

My stack now is to think **how to submit this multiple value in the form in one submit button**. So what I want to achieve is like this:

```
INSERT INTO  `product` (  `productname` ,  `price` ,  `image`) 
VALUES ('Product 1',  '$10',  'product-1.jpg'), 
       ('Product 2',  '$20',  'product-2.jpg'),
       ('Product 3',  '$30',  'product-3.jpg');
```

Since I don't know how much the product they are going to submit which it also mean how many values that is needed to the sql, my question now is how to automatically add value based on the number of the input that is needed.

I hope anyone understand what I am going to achieve here.

---

**[UPDATE QUESTION 1]**

I have tried it like this as how Arif_suhail_123 suggested:

```
<?php
$mysql_hostname = "myhost.com";
$mysql_user = "myname";
$mysql_password = "mypassword";
$mysql_database = "database-one";

$connection=mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Can't connect to mysql");
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $connection) or die("Can't Select Database");

for($i=0; $i<count($_POST['product_name']);$i++)
    {
        $product_name=$_POST['product_name'][$i];
        $product_price=$_POST['product_price'][$i];

        //Run your query here. 

        $mysql_query="INSERT INTO  `member_cart` (  `product_cart_name` ,  `product_cart_price`) 
                  VALUES ('$product_name',  '$product_price')";

        $result=  mysql_query($connection, $mysql_query) 
                  or die(mysql_error($connection));//here $connection is your 
       //database connection

    }
 ?>
```

My form:

```
    if(isset($_SESSION["products"])) {
    $total = 0;
    echo '<ol>';
    echo '<form action="cart-post-config.php" method="POST">>';
    foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm) {
                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td></td>';
                    echo '<td><input type="text" name="product_name[]"value='.$cart_itm["name"].'/></td>';
                    echo '<td><input type="text" name="product_price[]"value='.$cart_itm["price"].'/></td>';
                    echo '<td>View Save Delete</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" />';
    echo '</form>';//close the form
}
else {
    echo 'Your Cart is empty'; }
```

---

**[UPDATE QUESTION 2]**

I have tried it like this as how Umair suggested:

```
<?php
$mysql_hostname = "....";
$mysql_user = ".....";
$mysql_password = ".....";
$mysql_database = ".......";

$connection=mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Can't connect to mysql");
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $connection) or die("Can't Select Database");

$query =  "INSERT INTO  `member_cart` (  `product_cart_name` ,  `product_cart_price`) VALUES"; 

$values = array(); 
$total_products=0;
foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm) {             
        $values[] = "('{$cart_itm['product_name']}',  '{$cart_itm['product_price']}')";
        $total_products++;
    }

print "Total products are ".$total_products;
//final query
$query = implode(",",$values);

?>
```

But it always prints that `Total products are 0` even though I have fetch some products in the all related inputs.

Please Help

Comment: You should write query in loop or multiple times to do the same.

Comment: most likely you need a loop, its too broad. we don't even know what the markup looks like and how values are push inside a container (session?).

Comment: can you add the data you are getting after submitting the form?

Comment: I update my question with the session. Please check it again to make it clear how to help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this

Please read the comment in the answer

```
<?php 
echo '<form action="Your_File_name" method="POST">';
foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm) {//store them in array
                    echo '<input type= "text" name="product_name[]" value='.$cart_itm["product_name"].'/>';
                    echo '<input type= "text" name="product_price[]" value='.$cart_itm["prduct_price"].'/>';
    }

    echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" />';
    echo '</form>';//close the form

        //use array filter to remove the empty value
$product_name=array_filter($_POST['product_name']);//remove the empty value
$product_price=array_filter($_POST['product_price']);//remove the empty value

for($i=0; $i<count($product_name);$i++)//run a for loop, on the new array. 
    {


        $product=$product_name[$i];
        $price=$product_price[$i];
         $mysql_query="INSERT INTO  `member_cart` (  `product_cart_name` ,  `product_cart_price`) 
                  VALUES ('$product',  '$price')"; //use the new variable to run the query

        $result=  mysql_query($connection, $mysql_query) 
                  or die(mysql_error($connection));//here $connection is your 
       //database connection

    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it Looks sensible. I will let you know whether it works or not.

Comment: You are missing many things there. But overall the code you give are working to achieve what I want to. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by declaring static variable to count the items whenever any one add item to cart and decrease it when they remove the item from cart.

Then you can use this variable to find the number of items in cart and can run loop accordingly.

I hope, it helps.

Comment: I have declared the static variable in my update question (please to have a look at that) but why doesn't it work? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see a SESSION containing the Cart products. You can try something simlar to this.

```
$query =  "INSERT INTO  `product` (  `productname` ,  `price` ,  `image`) VALUES"; 

$values = array(); 
$total_products=0;
foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm) {             
    $values[] =
               "('{$cart_itm['product_name']}',  '{$cart_itm['product_price']}',  
                 '{$cart_itm['product_image']}')";
      $total_products++;
    }
print "Total products are ".$total_products;
//final query
$query .= implode(",",$valuse);
```

Comment: In this case we know that the user will submit three products (product 1, product 2, product 3) but the problem is we don't know how many product they will submit.

Comment: Number of products are equal to the number of times `foreach` runs

Comment: I will check it. I will confirm it to you whether it works or not.

Comment: In you updated question, you are creating query in FOREACH and running the query again and for each product. FOr example, you have 10 products, then query will run 10 times.
Why not follow my answer? It will write query for inserting as many items and will run query only once

Comment: Can you please edit again your answer with seems similar to what I have. Because you don't put the submit button and the post method there. It will much help me. Please.

Comment: I have used your code, but it prints that `total products are 0` even though I have post some product there.

Comment: Please see My Update Question two where I combined it with your code.

Comment: does `var_dump($_SESSION["products"])` shows anything?

Comment: Can you access `$_SESSION['products']` on the page where you are running my code> if yes... then I dont now what is the problem ... :(

Answer (score 0):

Make it like this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO  `product` (  `productname` ,  `price` ,  `image`) Values";

while(Statement){ //(Or a for statement)
       $query .= "(".$somevar1.",".$somevar2.",".$somevar3."),";
}

$query .= ";";
//execute your query here.
```

Adjust it to your code, so that it works properly for your code, you have to see what you can use the best, a for or a while loop. That's up to you.